# AngularJS: Evaluating expressions in templateUrl function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am pretty new to angularjs but I am now trying to do some things :). I wrote a first easy directive like:

```
angular.module('coc')
  .directive('icon', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: true,
      templateUrl: function(element, attributes) {
        return 'img/icons/' + attributes.icon + '.svg';
      }
    }
  });
```

I'm gonna call it like:
`<icon icon="home"></icon>` which works pretty well. It includes as desired. `img/icons/home.svg`

But if I try to bind it to a scope variable it won`t work

```
Try to include icon: {{icon}}
<icon icon="{{icon}}"></icon>
```

Gives the output:

```
Try to include icon: home
(console.log): Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: img/icons/{{icon}}.svg (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: `attributes.icon` get string attribute value `{{icon}}` and past it as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <icon icon="icon"></icon>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.icon = 'home';
}])
.directive('icon', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {icon: '='},
        template: '<img ng-src="img/icons/{{icon}}.svg">'
    }
});
```

Comment: looks good it must be working but I think it's better to keep an isolated scope

Comment: oh no problema just add `scope: {icon: '=icon'}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `icon` variable with directive scope. like below -

```
angular.module('coc')
  .directive('icon', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        icon: "=icon"
      },
      templateUrl: function(element, attributes) {
        return 'img/icons/' + attributes.icon + '.svg';
      }
   }
 });
```

Comment: This would work using the scope value instead of attributes

Comment: @ThibaudL but you can't use scope value inside templateUrl function :-)

Comment: @Grundy Yeah I should have added to not use a templateUrl function ^^ eather a simple template or a templateUrl pointing to a template file

Answer (score 0):

@Vishnu Atrai was close : 
Always try to use an isolated scope

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        icon: "="
    },
    template: '<img ng-src="img/icons/{{icon}}.svg">'
}
```